# Set windows to automatically restart instead of require user action on Recovery screen

Tags: windows-10

Try to configure this computer to automatically restart when power is restored after a power outage.

I was able to set the BIOS settings so enable this. However, sometimes windows throws this screen up requiring user interaction. This probably happens because the power was suddenly cut and windows doesn't like that so had to repair itself.

If I select "Restart" or a similar option under "See Advanced Repair Options", the computer restarts and loads just fine.

How do I configure windows to do this automatically? The reason is that sometimes I'm not physically there and need to be able to log into the computer remotely (which won't work using the options I know of until after this step in the start-up process)

[image]

Comment: Have you investigated the event logs to see why it might be going into the recovery state? Maybe solving that issue might prevent this from occurring. I'm not sure if [disabling automatic repair on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-automatic-repair-windows-10) would be recommended but another way to prevent it but not sure if it'd boot right to Windows when it'd otherwise go here. Then there is a KVM with web interface you give an IP and connect to see screen and control keyboard and mouse at console level not requiring the OS so you can press the options. Any other way?

Comment: I agree. This message is not likely because of power but rather the OS needs repair. Run DISM / SFC  and then if necessary a Windows 10 Repair Install.